# Is it possible in C# to create a very simple value type for IBAN, BIC?

Tags: c#

Is it possible in C# to create a very simple value type for IBAN, BIC (maybe with `struct`)? That automatically works for features like Json Serialization and EF Core saving?

I would like to use the primitive type in data objects that are converted to Json and also in entities that are stored via EF Core

```
public class AccountTransaction
{
    public Iban RecipientIban { get; set; }
    public Bic RecipientBic { get; set; }
}
```

For instance for EF Core I dont wanna specify some value converter everytime I used those types. Or I dont wanna specify some custom JsonSerializer everytime those types are used in an object. They more or less should work like usual string.

Also the goal would be to achieve some automatic validations on assignment. e.g:

```
Iban ibanVariable = "ILLEGAL IBAN";
```

That such calls are leading to errors automatically. (Also on reading from database / deserializing Jsons, etc.)

Is there some simple way I could achieve this? Is there some `FromString()` thingy or assignment operator at `struct` that I could overwrite (like [operator-overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading))?

Comment: Why not just use a string? Introducing extra objects just so that the object is named what it represents does not introduce clarity in this case imo.

Comment: You can use define conversion operators in C#, more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators). Basically it allows you to implicitly or explicitly cast one Type to another

Comment: @TimKatheteStadler they goal is to introduce some automatic parsing and validating mechanism that throws / fails whenever a invalid string is assigned. even on parsing some json (from e.g: some request). And I dont wanna add this logic to every object that has an IBAN string. It should work implicetly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by using conversion operators. These basically allow you to define a conversion from one Type to another and back. These conversions can either be explicit, so you'll need to explicitly cast them every time, or they can be implicit, so it just does it. Here's an example:

```cs
public class Iban
{
    private readonly string _ibanString;

    public Iban(string iban)
    {
        _ibanString = iban;
    }

    public static implicit operator Iban(string iban) => new Iban(iban);
   
    public static implicit operator string(Iban iban) => iban._ibanString;
}
```

You can now do this:

```cs
Iban iban = "SOME IBAN";
```

A quick breakdown of the implicit/ explicit operator syntax and a link to the MSDN documentation:

Basically, a operator must always be `public static` followed by either the `implicit` or `explicit` keyword, then follows the type which will be returned (much like for a method), and then finally you can specify exactly one argument to use to convert from. After that you can either do like I did and use the expression body syntax from a method or use an actual body with `{ ... return foo; }` and all.

And here is the promised MSDN link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators

**Note 1:** I just re read your title and you were asking for a value type, it's just as easy. All you need to do is replace `public class Iban` with `public struct Iban`.

**Note 2:** When you have implicitly defined operators on a class you can use explicit casting, but when you only have explicitly defined operators on a class you cannot implicitly cast them. So with implicit operators this is perfectly legal:

```cs
var iban = (Iban) "SOME IBAN";
```

But when you have explicit operators the following becomes illegal and you'll have to explicitly cast it:

```cs
// Throws a compiler error
Iban iban = "SOME IBAN"
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. `explicit` operators could be added as well for convenience and completeness.

Comment: A class can only implement an operator either implicitly or explicitly, not both. But when implementing an operator implicitly you can also explicitly cast it, so `var iban = (Iban) "SOME IBAN";` would also work

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks for clearifying. It actually sounds quite logical when thinking a bit more about it.

Comment: @MindSwipe this is awesome and exactly what I looked for! I hope it works out of the box with EF Core and Json searilization

Comment: @grafbumsdi I'm afraid it won't, I just tried it with Reflection and EF (at least to my knowledge) uses it to set property values. Although I found a solution to solving this with TypeConverter, let me research a little

Comment: @MindSwipe i tried with InMemory context with EF Core and it was working, but let's see when we get to SQL and Json serialization. so far it's working fine.

Comment: I have to admit that the fact that you can do that is very cool. Still, I think it is convenient to favor creating the Iban using either the constructor or a Factory Method, and serializing it using custom JsonConverters in the case that you want for example.